# Can we create a half moon like arc in css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create image arc like below. I am able to make semicircle but I am not sure how to make the center more thick and outer side thinner of an arc.

Or should I use a image of the arc.

**Arc style:**

[image: Arc style]

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Post the code you have so far

Comment: Are you trying to draw the arc exclusively with CSS?

Answer (score 2):

This is very easily done using a pseudo element.

To make it thinner at its end's one set the border width to 0 on all side but the right.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: lightgreen;
  margin: 40px;
}
div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  top: -30px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0 solid lightgreen;
  border-width: 0 5px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div>JK</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @LGSon I was not able to figure out for border width.

Comment: border-width... I forgot about that one and it's exactly what I needed for my project. Easy & powerful.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html{
background:black;
}

#moon {
  color:lightgreen;
  line-height: 110px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:30px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-right:6px solid lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div id="moon">
JK
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to draw your arc with CSS (and you aren't supporting certain legacy browsers), you can achieve the effect by manipulating the border of an element as in this prototype example…

```css
.arc {
  height: 100px;
  width: 80px;
  border: 0 solid #f00;
  border-right-width: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.arc>span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 15px;
  transform: translateY( -50%);
  color: #f00;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arc"><span>Foo</span></div>
```

Which has the added advantage of not obscuring the background of the element behind it with a solid color, too.